# Ошибка при вызове объекта из массива

Tags: delphi

Есть рабочий код:

```
Private
  PrArr_Image: array of TJPEGImage;
…
var
  LImageStream: TMemoryStream;
  L_BMP: TBitmap;
  L_JPG, q1: TJPEGImage;
begin
…
    while not (ibqEmpty1.Eof) do
    begin
      try
        LImageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        L_BMP := TBitmap.Create;
       L_JPG := TJPEGImage.Create;
       q1 := TJPEGImage.Create;
            L_BMP.LoadFromStream(LImageStream);
             L_JPG.Assign(L_BMP);
           PrArr_Image[0] := L_JPG;
             q1.Assign(PrArr_Image[0]);
           dbViewImage.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, q1);
 …
      finally
     LImageStream.Free;
       L_BMP.Free;
      L_JPG.Free;
       q1.Free;
         end;
 end;
```

в котором, из потока я получаю картинку «bmp», перевожу ее в формат «jpg», гружу ее в динамический массив, потом для проверки (сохранения ее в массиве), сразу вывожу ее в «DrawGrid» – все нормально.

Потом я по нажатию кнопки опять хочу ее вывести в «DrawGrid» уже из массива:

```
procedure TFMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  q1: TJPEGImage;
begin
      showmessage(IntToStr(Length(PrArr_Image)));    
  dbViewImage.DefaultDrawing := false;
  q1 := TJPEGImage.Create;
  q1.Assign(PrArr_Image[0]); // <-- ошибка тут
  dbViewImage.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, q1);
  q1.Free;
end;
```

и тут облом на 3-ей строке.

> EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00403B8C in module 'CF.exe'

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrArr_Image[0] := L_JPG;` просто копирует указатель на объект, `L_JPG.Free;` уничтожает объект, а `PrArr_Image[0]` становится указателем на освобожденную память (мусор).

Насколько я помню, графические объекты можно копировать через `Assign` (он у тебя кстати есть в коде). Скопировать произвольный объект - обычно нельзя.

Попробуй не делать `L_JPG.Free;`. Таким образом у тебя массив `PrArr_Image` будет содержать все объекты.

P.S. На самом деле код надо немного причесать, щас запутанная логика.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего при присвоении элементу массива значения переменной на самом деле просто копируется указатель (переменная, содержащая объект, на самом деле указатель), поэтому когда вы делаете `Free`, а потом пытаетесь обратиться к переменной из массива, происходит обращение к невыделенной памяти. Попробуйте повесить бряк на обращение к элементу массива и посмотрите в дебаггере, что лежит в этой переменной. Или проверьте `Cardinal(Pointer(PrArr_Image[0])) = Cardinal(Pointer(L_JPG))`. Если они равны, значит мои догадки верны.

Comment: Все верно. `PrArr_Image[0] := L_JPG;` просто копирует указатель на объект, `L_JPG.Free;` уничтожает объект, а `PrArr_Image[0]` становится указателем на освобожденную память (мусор)

Comment: **А как скопировать объект, а не указатель?**  Все Верно, когда я, закоментировал "L_JPG.Free;", все заработало...

Comment: Насколько я помню, графические объекты можно копировать через `Assign` (он у тебя кстати есть в коде). Скопировать произвольный объект - обычно нельзя.

Comment: А как тогда мне поступить? Мне нужно создать динамический массив графических объектов/рисунков. Может как-то через "TObjectList" попробывать? Если это правильно конечно будет?

Comment: Попробуй не делать `L_JPG.Free;`. Таким образом у тебя массив `PrArr_Image` будет содержать все объекты. На самом деле код надо немного причесать, щас запутанная логика.

Comment: Да Вы правы, если его не очищать. Вообще  я думал можно записывать только одно изображение (одну картинку). А оно оказывается может хранить множество изображений. И соответственно я к ним могу обращаться q1.Assign(PrArr_Image[0]); q1.Assign(PrArr_Image[1]); q1.Assign(PrArr_Image[2]); Тогда вообще может можно без PrArr_Image, как-то обойтись? Или массив нужен для хранения указателей на конкреные изображения?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25911/discussion-between-konstantin78-and-krom-stern).